# How do I clip Tailwind CSS" "backdrop-invert" to text?

Tags: tailwind-css

So I'm trying to create this NavBar component where the NavBar always sits at the top of the page, and when you scroll, the page contents scroll behind the NavBar. I want the text color in the NavBar to invert the color of whatever is currently sitting behind the text. I'm currently using backdrop-invert, but I can't clip the effect to the text.

Here is my code:

```
const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <div className="sticky top-0 flex py-10 backdrop-invert bg-clip-text">
            <div className="grow text-center text-2xl font-bold ">Morningside Automation</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

This site is also a good example of what I'm attempting to replicate:
https://kjell-template.framer.website/

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

That site you linked, uses

```css
mix-blend-mode: difference
```

The tailwind equivalent of that is `mix-blend-difference`.

Thanks for the question, this helped me fix my issue!